# Are $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z^2-3|<1\}$ and $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z^2-1|<3\}$ complex domains?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I got stuck on the following problem:

> Which of the following sets are domains in the complex plane:
> $$D_1=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z^2-3|<1\}$$
> $$D_2=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z^2-1|<3\}$$

These sets are domains if they are arcwise connected open non-empty subsets of the complex plane. I first tried to sketch these regions to get some intuition about the problem. I tried the following :
If we let $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $z^2=r^2e^{2i\theta}=r^2(\cos2\theta+\sin2\theta)$ and our inequality becomes:
$$|z^2-3|^2=|r^2(\cos2\theta+\sin2\theta)-3|^2=(r^4\cos^22\theta-6r^2\cos2\theta+9)+r^4\sin^22\theta=r^2(r^2-6\cos2\theta)+9<1$$

If we let $\theta=0$, then $r^2(r^2-6)<-8\implies r\in (\sqrt2,2)$, since $r>0$. And of course if z is a real number and $z\in(-2,-\sqrt2)$ then $|z^2-3|<1$. So if $\theta=0$ and z lies in $(-2,-\sqrt2)\cup(\sqrt2,2)$ it satisfies the inequality. But what if $\theta\neq0$? I have tried a lot, but only got so far. I think that the first one is not a domain, since we will get two distinct open sets U and V such that their intersection is  empty and union equal to $D_1$. Hence it is not arcwise connected, for example there is no path from -2 to 2 without leaving this region.

For the second one a similar approach as above gives us the inequality( if we again let $z=re^{i\theta}$) :
$$ r^2(r^2-2\cos2\theta)<2$$
How to determine wether $D_2$ is a domain ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proving that $D_1$ and $D_2$ are open is not so hard, for instance by noting that for any $a \in \mathbb{C}$ the map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R} : z \mapsto |z^2 - a|$ is continuous.  But I don't think you struggle with this?

For $D_1$ your intuition is correct! To prove it is not connected it suffices of course to find two members that cannot be connected by a path. For this it suffices to look at $\sqrt{3}$ and $-\sqrt{3}$. If we could connect them by a path $\gamma : [0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ lying completely in $D_1$, then that would mean that $\gamma$ intersects the imaginary axis. (Why? It's intuitive but to make it rigourous: apply the intermediate value theorem to a specific function ...) Howewer no purely imaginary number $ai$ is in  $D_1$, a contradiction.

For $D_2$ you can show that you can connect any two elements $z_1, z_2 \in D_2$ by first taking a straight line path from $z_1$ to $0$ and then from $0$ to $z_2$. You can prove that this total path will lie completely in $D_2$ using your inequality. Try to visualize this ;) (Hint: the argument $\theta$ of $\gamma(t)$ stays constantly that of either $z_1$ or $z_2$ because it's a straight line to/from $0$). It's a good exercise to write out equations and really try to make everything rigorous here.

Good luck!

Comment: We require the path $\gamma$ to be smooth so it is continuos and by the intermediate value theorem it must pass the imaginairy axis. So there is $t\in[0,1]$ such that $\gamma(t)=ai$. This would mean $ai\in D_1$ since the curve lies entirely in $D_1$. It must satisfy $|(ai)^2-3|=|3+a^2|<1$. Since a is real $|a^2+3|=a^2+3$ and $a^2+3<1\implies a^2<-2$ and this is not possible which means such a path does not exists. And how do i draw such a region just to see how it looks like any tips on that. Thx by the way

Comment: @muhammedgunes Hi. No problem. No, your path does not need to be smooth, only continuous. Remark that our path for $D_2$ is not smooth for instance since we make a corner at $0$. But this is no problem. Yes that's true by the intermediate value theorem; to make it rigorous you can look at the map $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} : t \mapsto \text{Re}(\gamma(t))$. As a composition of functions this is continuous, it is negative in $0$ and positive in $1$ and so by the intermediate value theorem it must become zero: this yields us a purely imaginary $\gamma(t_0)$.

Comment: The rest of what you say is correct. I do not know how to draw this.  To come to the solution I just noticed that elements near $\sqrt{3}$ and $-\sqrt{3}$ will be in $D_1$ (but for some weird shape, will not be a disc), while elements more far off will not, like $0$ or any imaginary number. For $D_2$ I thought the opposite, and then noticed using your inequality that a straightline path connected with $0$ works. To closest I can give to intuition is that $D_2$ it's somehow the union of 'radius' $\sqrt{3} 'blobs' around $\pm 1$, but not nice disks but a bit mishaped due to the squaring ...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f:\Bbb C\rightarrow\Bbb C$, $f(z)=z^2$ and the open sets $E_1=\{w:|w-3|<1\}$ and $E_2=\{w:|w-1|<3\}$.

a) $f^{-1}(E_1)=D_1=C_1\cup(-C_1)$ has two components, So it is not a domain.

b) $f^{-1}(E_2)=D_2$ has one component. It is domain since $f$ is continuous.